# In Magento2 UpgradeSchema, Don't we have addColumns to add more columns to a table?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

In Magento2 UpgradeSchema we have a function as,

```
$setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $setup->getTable('quote'),
        'testColumn',
        [
            'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'length' => 32,
            'nullable' => false,
            'default' => '',
        ]
    );
```

to add columns to the existing table. But if we want to add more than 1 column to a existing table do we have any options like,

```
$setup->getConnection()->addColumns(
        $setup->getTable('quote'),
        'testColumn1',
        [
            'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'length' => 32,
            'nullable' => false,
            'default' => '',
        ],
        'testColumn1',
        [
            'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'length' => 32,
            'nullable' => false,
            'default' => '',
        ]
    );
```

instead of doing `addColumn` more than 1 time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have used the same. OOC i have searched for addColumns function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think there is no direct way to update column which you are asking.**

When you call `addColumn` method from your upgrade schema it calls

`\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql` which `implements` `\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface`

```
 public function addColumn($tableName, $columnName, $definition, $schemaName = null)
    {
        if ($this->tableColumnExists($tableName, $columnName, $schemaName)) {
            return true;
        }

        $primaryKey = '';
        if (is_array($definition)) {
            $definition = array_change_key_case($definition, CASE_UPPER);
            if (empty($definition['COMMENT'])) {
                throw new \Zend_Db_Exception("Impossible to create a column without comment.");
            }
            if (!empty($definition['PRIMARY'])) {
                $primaryKey = sprintf(', ADD PRIMARY KEY (%s)', $this->quoteIdentifier($columnName));
            }
            $definition = $this->_getColumnDefinition($definition);
        }

        $sql = sprintf(
            'ALTER TABLE %s ADD COLUMN %s %s %s',
            $this->quoteIdentifier($this->_getTableName($tableName, $schemaName)),
            $this->quoteIdentifier($columnName),
            $definition,
            $primaryKey
        );

        $result = $this->rawQuery($sql);

        $this->resetDdlCache($tableName, $schemaName);

        return $result;
    }
```

In this method you can see this this accept only single parameter. **Even `Magento` team calling `addColumn` every time.**

For example, just look at this `\Magento\Catalog\Setup\UpgradeSchema` in `addSupportVideoMediaAttributes` method

```
 $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $setup->getTable(Gallery::GALLERY_TABLE),
            'media_type',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'length' => 32,
                'nullable' => false,
                'default' => ImageEntryConverter::MEDIA_TYPE_CODE,
                'comment' => 'Media entry type'
            ]
        );
        $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $setup->getTable(Gallery::GALLERY_TABLE),
            'disabled',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
                'unsigned' => true,
                'nullable' => false,
                'default' => 0,
                'comment' => 'Visibility status'
            ]
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no function called `addColumns`, so try below code.

```
$columns = [
    [
        $setup->getTable('quote'),
        'testColumn1',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'length' => 32,
                'nullable' => false,
                'default' => '',
            ]
    ],
    [
        $setup->getTable('quote'),
        'testColumn2',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'length' => 32,
                'nullable' => false,
                'default' => '',
            ]
    ]
];

foreach($columns as $column){
    $setup->getConnection()->addColumn($column);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(
        SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {

            $columns = [
                            [
                                $setup->getTable('tablename'),
                                'ecommercename',
                                [
                                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                    'length' => 255,
                                    'nullable' => false,
                                    'default' => '',
                                    'comment' => 'ECommerceName'
                                ]
                            ],
                            [
                                $setup->getTable('tablename'),
                                'description',
                                [
                                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                    'length' => 255,
                                    'nullable' => false,
                                    'default' => '',
                                    'comment' => 'Description'
                                ]
                            ],
                            [
                                $setup->getTable('tablename'),
                                'address',
                                [
                                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                    'length' => 255,
                                    'nullable' => false,
                                    'default' => '',
                                    'comment' => 'Address'
                                ]
                            ],
                            [
                                $setup->getTable('tablename'),
                                'city',
                                [
                                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                    'length' => 255,
                                    'nullable' => false,
                                    'default' => '',
                                    'comment' => 'City'
                                ]
                            ],
                            [
                                $setup->getTable('tablename'),
                                'city',
                                [
                                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                    'length' => 255,
                                    'nullable' => false,
                                    'default' => '',
                                    'comment' => 'City'
                                ]
                            ],
                            [
                                $setup->getTable('tablename'),
                                'state',
                                [
                                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                    'length' => 255,
                                    'nullable' => false,
                                    'default' => '',
                                    'comment' => 'State'
                                ]
                            ],
                            [
                                $setup->getTable('tablename'),
                                'zip',
                                [
                                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                    'length' => 255,
                                    'nullable' => false,
                                    'default' => '',
                                    'comment' => 'zip'
                                ]
                            ],
                            [
                                $setup->getTable('tablename'),
                                'eoms_exclude_not_local',
                                [
                                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                    'length' => 255,
                                    'nullable' => false,
                                    'default' => '',
                                    'comment' => 'Eoms Exclude Not Local'
                                ]
                            ]
                        ];


                  foreach ($columns as $key => $column){
                        $installer->getConnection()->addColumn($column[0], $column[1], $column[2]);
                  }
        }
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please upgrade the version in the module.xml file before running s:up.